# The user icon won't change except in the developer story section

Tags: support, developer-story, profile-picture

I changed my profile picture a couple of hours ago. It changed only in the developer story section.

But the old profile picture is still there.

**Is that a bug or I need a certain privilege to completely update my profile picture?**

*Note: I have seen some users with a certain profile picture but when I enter to see their profile the picture changes.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out:

**I can update my profile picture from another place in settings:**

So there's probably an 2 pictures: one for the developer profile and another for the account profile.

[image]

Comment: That's correct. There are two different pictures. It's what allows me to have a holiday-themed avatar here on Stack Overflow, while not affecting my "all-business" CV/Developer Story.